# WatchKit how do I perform a specific segue with an identifier

Tags: segue, watchkit, apple-watch

I have a button that is already hooked up in the InterfaceBuilder to bring up a modal interface controller.  In some cases I'd like to trigger this transition programmatically but I can't find a way to perform that same segue in Watchkit.  I know you can do this in iphones/iOS but so far I can't find it in the Watchkit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done programatically. You need to set the Identifier in the storyBoard for the interface.

If you want it to present modally

```
presentControllerWithName("Identifier", context: nil)
```

If you want to push

```
pushControllerWithName("Identifier", context: nil)
```

You can set context if you like. You can retrieve it in the controller you push/present

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the new calls:

```
presentController(withName: "Identifier", context: nil)
pushController(withName: "Identifier", context: nil)
```